Express c.d.f. of $Y$ in terms of $F_X$
I specially need help on the last case, where $t\ge a$. Can you give some advice??
Let $ X $ be a random variable with distribution function $ F_X(x) $, and let $a$ be constant.
Calculate the distribution function of $ Y $ in terms of the distribution function of $ X $.
$$
Y=\begin{cases}
      X & \text{if } X<a\\
      a & \text{if } X\ge a
    \end{cases}
$$
Notice that $ Y $ is defined as $ \text{min}\{X,a\} $ with $ F_Y(t):=P(Y\le t) $ and defining $ t<a $ and $ t\ge a $, where $ t $ are values that the variable $ X $ can take, thus ensuring that $ Y $ takes the values $ X $ or $ a $. That is:
If $ t<a $,
We seek $ P(Y\le t) $ and for $ Y\le t $, we need to analyze the conditions that satisfy this. If $ Y=X $, then $ X $ must be $ \le t $ for it to be true that $ Y\le t $, but this only happens when $ X<a $, only if $ Y=X $. Thus, $ Y<t $ is equivalent to $ X<t $ if and only if $ Y=X $ if and only if $ X<a $, so $ F_Y(t)=P(Y\le t)=P(X\le t)=F_X(t) $
If $ t\ge a $,
We seek $ P(Y\le t) $ and in this case, given that if $ X\ge a $, then $ X\in[a,\infty) $, therefore, if $ Y\le t $ and $ t=X $, then $ t\in[a,\infty) $ and by the definition of $ Y $, we have that if $ t=a $, $ Y=a $; if $ t\ge a $, $ Y=a $, and in both cases, $ Y\le a $, so $ a $ is the maximum value that $ Y $ can take. Now, $ t\ge a $ implies $ P(Y\le a) $ and the event $ Y\le a $ considers all possible values of $ Y $ such that $ Y\le a $, therefore, $P(Y\le a)=1$
Then we have
$$
    F_Y(t)=\begin{cases}
        F_X(t) & t<a\\
        1 & t\ge a
    \end{cases}
    $$

The end result is correct but esp. the proof in the case $t\ge a$ is totally overcomplicated. Why do you show $t\in[a,\infty)$ if that was the case you assumed you are in?

I wanted to show that $a$ is the maximum value that $Y$ can take

This is trivial by the very definition of $Y=\min{X,a}$ and it does not depend on $t,.$
